# How to set up Laravel 5.1 on Openshift?

Tags: laravel, openshift

Openshift only has Laravel 5.0 offered as an application, and PHP 5.4 application. However Laravel 5.1 need PHP 5.5.9+. So has anybody tried to set up Laravel 5.1 on Openshift successfully? Some helps needed. Thanks.

Comment: You should explains the problem, what you have tried, which errors do you have... That's how StackOverflow works:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find a way to install PHP 5.6 by using https://github.com/JVerstry/openshift-php-framework-stack , but the sad thing is that when I tried to install Laravel 5.1 based on it, it automatically used OpenShift's own PHP (5.3.3). Even I tried export my own PHP into path, the installation would still fail.

I gave it up. A pity that Openshift doesn't offer Laravel 5.1 support. I switched to [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=ca790c346da7) and it saved my day. I am using Laravel 5.2.37 & PHP 7.0.7 on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=ca790c346da7) now.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to install php 5.6 on openshift as of now. The PHP cartridge available is only 5.4. so you have no choice but to wait :|

Answer (score 1):

- Create HHVM Application
- Then Clone the current application repo in local machine

**Create laravel app**

- using laravel installer

  laravel new test
- using composer

  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test

**Then move all file including hidden files from test to laravel52 (cloned folder) folder**

- remove /vendor and .env line from .gitgnore file

Edit NGINX server config file
which is located at

**config/nginx.d/default.conf.erb**

Change:

```
root  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %><%= ENV['NGINX_WWW_ROOT'] %>;
```

To:

```
root  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>public;
```

change:

```
location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

To:

```
location / {

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }
```

save default.conf.erb file and git commit

```
git add .
git commit -am "fix nginx server"
git push
```

After that visit site, you should see laravel welcome page.

Note: When you connect database, don't forget to put openshift database variable in .env file.

source [ubutnu nepal blog](http://ubuntu-nepal.blogspot.com/2016/01/host-laravel-52-in-openshift-for-free.html)